# Update single section of multi-section UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewController` created in storyboard. It has two sections. The first section's rows contain controls laid-out in storyboard. I want to update the rows in the second section using values in an array.

I'm fairly new to iOS development. I understand how to use a `UITableViewDataSource` to update a table based on the array, but not how to restrict the updates to a specific section. Can anyone outline how to do this?

**EDIT** This seemed like a simple problem, so I thought I code would just obscure the question. Maybe I was wrong. Heres what I have:

My `numberOfRowsInSection` function returns 1 in the section number is 0, because the first section (the one I designed in storyboard) has a single row, otherwise it returns the number of elements in the backing data array:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return [myData length];
}
```

My `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function creates a cell if the section number is 1. But I don't know what to do if the section number is zero. How do I avoid having to recreate the rows I laid-out in storyboard?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   if(indexPath.section == 1)
   {
       cell.textLabel.text = [myData objectAtindex:indexPath.row]; 
   }
   else
   {
       // What to do here?
   }
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific, what you actually want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well If you only have few static controls in the first section why won't you put these controls in a table header view instead? Thus you'll only have one section to worry about :)

Comment: I know I can do this programatically, but I can't find a way to add the controls to the header in storyboard. Is this possible?

Comment: I think if you drag an empty uiview from the objects library to the tableview in storyboard that would work.

Comment: well then the user will probably have to style all these controls to look like tableViewCells. Much more effort than reloading the section

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin maybe he's holding these controls in a section as a work around. they don't necessarily look like table rows or whatever. a header view would be a better solution in this case.

Comment: BTW, I wanted to add this answer as a comment on the question but it appears that i don't have the necessary reputation points :)

Comment: @EdLess `The first section's rows contain controls laid-out in storyboard` ..... the user has said he is using the rows. Therefore, adding these to a header is way outside what the user asked for

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin dude you're focusing on one case and treating it as if it were the only case. The "user" didn't explain much to judge things like this. I think it's better if he attached some screenshots of the table view in storyboard

Comment: (OP here) The controls in the first section are a text box and a button. Clicking the button does a search against an external web service using the string in the text box. I want to display the results in the second section.

Comment: So in this case. Holding a section for these controls is not necessary at all. Did you figure out how to add a header view in storyboard?

Comment: @Ed. I can't see a way to do this, but I'm relatively new to storyboard. Genuine question: why do you feel that putting he controls in a section is "not necessary"?

Comment: Do you know how to drag a UIView from the object library in the utilities sidebar? (how did you lay out the controls in your section?) Drag one to the table view and snap it on the top. As for your question; sections should hold table cells... Table header views and even section header views are there so you can achieve what you're trying to achieve here. Using a section view is, for lack of a better metaphor, like using tape to fix your broken car wind shield, it might work for a while but maintaining it is not that easy.

Comment: @Ed. Ok that works, and I have a single-section listview. Thank you! Being new to UIKit, I think I got a couple of things wrong here. Firstly, I incorrectly thought that a `UIListViewController` could only have a single `UIListView` as its top-level view object, precluding having a separate container for the textbox and button. Thats why I put them in their own section. Secondly, I thought you were suggesting somehow adding the controls to the *listview's* header, rather than just a header view above the listview. That was what I couldn't find a way to do in storybd. Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: @AndyJohnson You're welcome! :) //you're an android developer, aren't you? :P in iOS we have 'UITableView' and 'UITableViewController' And yes UITableViewController can have one table with as many sections as you want, one table header view and one footer view. plus each section can have it's own header and footer view. You can create section header/footer views programmatically. While you can drag views to the table view in storyboard to create TABLE header & footer views if you wanted to.

Answer (score 1):

In your method `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`add this

Create 2 differents UITableViewCells and reference them like this

```
if (indexPath.section == 1) {
    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"DynamicCell";
    VideoCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    //You are drawing your second section so you can use your array as values

    cell.property1...
    cell.property2...
    cell.property3...

    return cell;

}else{//If you have only 2 sections then else represent your first section
    //You are drawing your first section
    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"StaticCell";
    VideoCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I considered this approach, but what do I return if indexPath.section is zero ? I don't want to programatically recreate the rows that I laid-out in storyboard.

Comment: section 0 represent the first section. An indexs begin in 0 so the first row in the first section has indexpath {0,0}

Comment: I know that! What do I return when `indexPath.section == 0`? The first section already contains rows created in storyboard. I don't want to have to re-create them programatically.

Comment: if section = 0 then return cell without changes

Comment: That doesn't work: the 'unchanged' cell is empty. I'm fairly sure that iOS doesn't guarantee that the `UITableViewCell` that it passes to `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is always the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the row value in the delegate method

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

To identify the section, just use:

```
indexPath.section
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) with an array of all the indexPaths that are in the wanted section, built with a loop and a `NSMutableArray`.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)reloadSections:(NSIndexSet *)sections 
      withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation;
```

The parameter "`section`" is An index set identifying the sections to reload.